# Photon 3-momentum in a frame given by a 4-velocity

Tags: special-relativity, lorentz-symmetry

The book Introduction to General Relativity by Hughston and Tod has the following statement in Chapter 3, Aspects of Special Relativistic Geometry, pages 29-30:

If a photon has four-momentum $P^a$ then its three-momentum, relative to the frame defined by a unit time-like vector $V^a$ is $E R^a=P^a - V^a P^b V_b$, where $E$ is the energy of the photon in that frame, and $R^a$ is the unit space-like vector pointing in the direction of the 3-momentum relative to that frame.

I find this statement strange. As far as I can tell, what they want to say is that $R^a=(0,\vec{R})$ is 0 and $\vec{R}$ is the unit 3-vector giving the direction of the momentum in that frame, but this does not seem to be true.

If I have $P^a=(\omega, \vec{p})$ and $V=\gamma (1,\vec{v})$, I have:
$V^b P_b = \gamma \omega- \gamma (\vec{p} \cdot \vec{v}) = \gamma(|\vec{p}|-\vec{p}\cdot\vec{v})$ and:

$$P^0 - V^0 P^b V_b = \omega - \gamma^2 (|\vec{p}|-\vec{p}\cdot\vec{v}) \neq 0$$

and the spatial components are:

$$\vec{p} - \gamma^2 \vec{v} (|\vec{p}|-\vec{p}\cdot\vec{v})$$

which is not what I expect, as this should be the Lorentz boosted version of $\vec{p}$, that is:

$$\vec{p} - \gamma |\vec{p}|\vec{v} + (\gamma-1)(\vec{p}\cdot\vec{v})\vec{v}/v^2 $$

Am I making a mistake somewhere? I do not think it is a typo in the book, since they repeat it 3 times.

Comment: In "this is equal to $ER^a$", what is "this" referring to ?

Comment: @LucasGautheron Typo corrected.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use the 4-momentum in one frame with a time-like unit 4-vector defining another frame. Take P, V and R for the same frame and the formula becomes rather trivial.

That is, in any given frame, momentum P decomposes into its projection along the time-like unit 4-vector V of that frame and an orthogonal (in Minkowski space) space-like unit 4-vector defining the direction of the 3-momentum in the same frame. Or explicitly, if 
$$
P = (E, \;\vec{p})\;, \;\;\; V = (1, \;\vec{0})\;, \;\;\; R = \left(0, \;\frac{\vec{p}}{p} \right)\;, 
$$
then
$$
V^b R_b = 0\;, \;\;\; P^b V_b = E\;,\;\;\;   P^b R_b = p = E\;,
$$
and
$$
P^a = \left(P^b V_b\right)V^a + \left( P^b R_b\right) R^a  \;\;\; \Leftrightarrow \;\;\;  E R^a = P^a - \left(P^b V_b\right)V^a
$$
The entire point is then that the above decomposition is Lorentz-covariant.

You may want to check that a similar reasoning applies to a massive particle, with the obvious difference that in this case there exists a rest frame.